# how call href ? on a while loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do a `while` to get a href at time but I don't know how call the `href`

I have tried to change edouard by `links['href']` but it doesn't work

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def validateString(edouard):

letter_flag = False

number_flag = False

while (edouard) is False:

    res= requests.get('')

    print(res.text)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

    for links in soup.find_all('a', class_="swatchanchor",href=True):
        edouard=(links['href'])

print(edouard)
```

> edouard is not defined

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question. Click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24110481) link to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is pretty much as error message. You call edouard in

```
while (edouard) is False:
```

but it is not yet defined.

Depending on what you really want to do you need to declare it before this line with

```
edouard  = False
```

I suspect there are others things to change but they can be for new questions.

Comment: i wanna do a loop until the script get a valid href